# Adaptive card sends error message when using ToggleVisibility action in MS Teams desktop app

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

This morning we started getting the standard bot error message in MS teams desktop client when using a card with toggleVisbility actions.  Selecting the button to toggle visbility on part of the card results in the below error, even though the toggle works as expected!

[bot error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eKux0.png)

The adaptive card code looks something like this:

```
{
                    "type": "ActionSet",
                    "actions": [
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "Alerts",
                            "targetElements": [
                                "Incidents",
                                {
                                    "elementId": "Metrics",
                                    "isVisible": false
                                },
                                {
                                    "elementId": "Admin",
                                    "isVisible": false
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "Action.ToggleVisibility",
                            "title": "Actions",
                            "targetElements": [
                                "ActionButton"
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }
```

This message would be expected if the bot app doesn't respond to a message/action, however the toggle action shouldn't be sending any data to the bot applicaiton.  I confirmed this in the teams web client using the network tracing dev tool.  When selecting the toggle action no new network calls are made.

We are not seeing this error in either the web client or the mobile client, only in Teams Desktop app.

This bot has been running for months without this issue and we didn't change the code, which makes me believe this is a MS teams side bug that was recently introduced.

Comment: Same issue is being tracked at https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/msteams-docs/issues/7626. Please follow the github thread for further updates.

Comment: The issue is fixed, we have tested this issue in Desktop Teams Version 1.6.00.3071 (64-bit). It is working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Also: This same issue was independently identified in the Adaptive Cards Project.
https://github.com/microsoft/AdaptiveCards/issues/8145

Comment: Please see [answering questions with links to other answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113437/answering-questions-with-links-to-other-answers-on-stackoverflow)